# Negative testing with Postman

Tags: postman

I haven't found any answer to this question on the internet (without having to pay for a course) so I'll ask here.

What is the best way to do negative test cases with Postman? For example, let's say I want to execute a graphql transaction and pass an invalid value for a given property. Normally the transaction will fail with some kind of validation error and the test will fail.

How can I do this so that I expect the error and the test passes when I receive the correct error message?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to do a try catch, catch the WebException and then put the error/tests inside the catch block.

```
 try
 {
     response = request.GetResponse();
 }
 catch (WebException)
 .
 .
 .
```

Comment: what is request.GEtResponse() ?

Comment: This is in the Test section for post processing.

Comment: There is no method getRespone() in postman